# Refraction vector (ray tracing)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometric-optics

I am doing ray tracing and I do the refraction of the ray using the following relation (I got it from [PDF "Reﬂections and Refractions in Ray Tracing"](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-10-summer/docs/2006--degreve--reflection_refraction.pdf)):

> $$\mathbf{t} = \frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}\mathbf{i} + \left(\frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}\cos{\theta_i} - \sqrt{1 - \sin^2{\theta_t}}\right)\mathbf{n} \tag{22}$$
>
> $$\sin^2{\theta_t} = \left(\frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}\right)^2\sin^2{\theta_i} = \left(\frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}\right)^2 (1 - \cos^2{\theta_i}) \tag{23}$$
>
> [image]

But I have seen it in another PDF as follows:

> $$\vec{t} = \frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}\vec{i} + \left(\frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}\cos{\theta_i} - \sqrt{1 - \sin^2{\theta_t}}\right)\vec{n} \tag{28}$$
>
> $$\sin^2{\theta_t} = \left(\frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}\right)^2\sin^2{\theta_i} = \left(\frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}\right)^2 (1 - \cos^2{\theta_i}) \tag{29}$$

Could you please explain for me why?

And how can I reassure that my refraction vector that I calculated is correct?

Comment: Presumably your question concerns the difference in sign conventions in the equation for the transmitted vector magnitude? Do you know the direction of the normal used in the second case?

Comment: I don't know the direction of the norm vector in the second one but even if the normal is in the other direction of the first one that should be (-n) and that should lead to the same equation of the first one but the (-) sign should be out of the brackets and that isn't the case in the second equation.

Answer (score 1):

I've added the homework tag even though it likely isn't. I think the best way to make sure of equations like this is simply to derive them yourself - that way you won't miss any quirky or unwonted conventions the author may be using.

So here we have the basic facts:

1. $\vec{i}$, $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{t}$ are all in the same plane;
2. We are free to make these vectors unit vectors if we like (they only define directions);
3. Snell's law

So, translate these into equations: (1) says that the three vectors are linearly dependent or:

$$\vec{t} = \alpha\,\vec{i} + \beta\,\vec{n};\;\alpha,\,\beta\in \mathbb{R}$$

(3) says that $n_1\, \vec{i} \wedge \vec{n} = n_2\, \vec{t} \wedge \vec{n}$ which simplifies to $n_1 = n_2 \alpha$. Now all we need is $|\vec{t}|^2 = \vec{t}\cdot \vec{t} = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 - 2 \alpha \beta \cos\theta_1 = 1$ and we can solve these equations to give the right expressions.

Comment: Changed $|\vec{t}|^2 = \vec{t}\cdot \vec{t} = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 + 2 \alpha \beta \cos\theta_1 = 1$ to $|\vec{t}|^2 = \vec{t}\cdot \vec{t} = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 - 2 \alpha \beta \cos\theta_1 = 1$ as this holds for the way that the OP has drawn the vectors